# C++ function for "kernel memory check" before accessing

Tags: windows, kernel, driver, c++14

I am developing a simple device driver for study. With a lot of testing, I am creating so many errors which finally leads my computer to blue screen. I am sure that the reason for this is memory crash. So now I want to check if my code can access to Kernel memory before going further.
My question is what function can check whether it is accessible or not in kernel memory. For instance, there is a pointer structure with two fields and I want to access the first field which is also a pointer but do now know whether it really has an accessible value or just trash value.
In this given context, I need to check it out to make sure that I am not getting blue screen.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Questions about kernel drivers need to have the relevant OS specified.  Also, C and C++ are different languages.  Your question seems to be about C++; if that is indeed your intent then remove the [c] tag.

Comment: As you said, I should've added OS version and language. Sorry about that.
Yes, Windows7 and C++ it is.

Comment: Best to do your testing on a separate computer or virtual machine so that the bluescreens aren't a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no equivalent for **kernel** memory, it's at the code's responsibility to ensure the desired addresses are valid and will be valid during access. If you get a **user-space** address - you can and you must use [`ProbeForRead`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559876(v=vs.85).aspx) or [`ProbeForWrite`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff559879(v=vs.85).aspx), but these are only for **user-space** buffer. Either of the two `ProbeForXxx` functions will just raise an exception when called with **kernel** memory address. *try-except* handlers won't help when accessing invalid **kernel** memory - Windows will simply bug check (crash) with [`PAGE_FAULT_IN_NONPAGED_AREA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x50--page-fault-in-nonpaged-area)

> For instance, there is a pointer structure with two fields and I want
> to access the first field which is also a pointer but do now know
> whether it really has an accessible value or just trash value.

Where did you get this pointer from? Who filled this structure? You must not check, you must know at beginning that this pointer is valid and the context of this structure will be valid during the time you use it, otherwise your code is already wrong and buggy.

Comment: Yes, In user mode, we can use that function "ProbeForRead" but in kernel mode case, from my test yesterday, I can access anywhere if the program is running at the same level such as Device drviers. The point is check if a pointer is surely pointing the right value or not.

Comment: @MinYoungLee - `In user mode, we can use that function "ProbeForRead"` - we can use it in **kernel** mode for check **user** mode address. but we can not check **kernel** mode address. you must know are address is valid but not check. simply question - from where you get this pointer ?